# Convert a CMSampleBuffer into a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, avcapturesession, cmsamplebufferref

Here's a function (code from Apple documentation) that converts a CMSampleBuffer into a UIImage

```
func imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage {
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    var imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    var baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    var bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    var width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
    var height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipLast.rawValue)
    var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    var quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    var image = UIImage(CGImage: quartzImage)!

    return image
}
```

When I try to visualize the UIImage using a UIImageView, I get nothing.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you getting errors in the Xcode output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution for **Swift 3.0**, where `CMSampleBuffer` is extended, creating a variable that gives you an optional `UIImage`.

```
import AVFoundation

extension CMSampleBuffer {
    var uiImage: UIImage? {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(self) else { return nil }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
        guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress,
                                      width: width,
                                      height: height,
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                      space: colorSpace,
                                      bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }
        guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else { return nil }

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0));

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get : <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 5120 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst

Comment: @Zigglzworth You may have a grayscale image. You can adjust the values accordingly for those.

Answer (score 4):

I just finished the exact same function in my current project, and here's how I got it to work (with a lot of googling and some trial-and-errors):

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue)
```

Also, make sure you present the UIImageView in the main thread (you are probably in the camera session thread to get the CMSampleBuffer), because UIKit can only be executed in main thread. Otherwise, you'll have to wait very, very long for the image to show.

Answer (score 4):

@Zigglzworth
Need setting kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA for captureVideoDataOutput

```
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
```